# Is there a built in driver I can access to get raw disk access on windows?

Tags: vb.net, disk, hard-drive

I'm using vb.net. Is there a way I can access a low-level driver or something like that in order to get raw disk access?

I'm meaning something like this:

```
Dim data(255) As Byte
data = ReadSector("C:", 5)
data(125) = asc("h")
data(126) = asc("e")
data(127) = asc("l")
data(128) = asc("l")
data(129) = asc("o")
WriteSector("C:", 5, data)
```

Where ReadSector has the arguments (drive As String, sector As Long) and WriteSector has (drive As String, sector As Long, data() As Byte).

This would write "hello" on the 126th character of the 5th sector on drive C.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [`DeviceIOCtrl()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, which lets you use the WinAP to do low-level disk access. If you're writing with VB.NET, it's going to be extremely difficult to use.

There isn't a simple `ReadSector` or `WriteSector` function, and there shouldn't be. Low-level access to the hard disk is not for beginning programmers; it's extremely easy to break an entire OS installation and/or lose data if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you. I realize the risks involved with this and i expect to break a drive or two. Good thing though, I'm gonna do this on a virtual machine. So if I break it, no harm done. I'm not _new_ at low level programming, however I am new at accessing low level drivers with high level languages. It would also benefit me to be able to treat a drive as a single file with read and write streams, however I'm sure it's not that simple.

Comment: I've given you the name of the WinAPI that's needed to write your own `ReadSector` and `WriteSector` functions, because they don't exist. The docs I linked give you information on the other API calls that are also needed, as well as some C++ sample code. There is no existing VB.net/C# framework or CLR functionality to do what you're asking. Surely if you're not new to low level programming,  writing the two wrapper functions shouldn't be a problem. :-) (Although I'm not sure VB.NET is the proper choice of language for doing so.) Good luck. :-)